# Key for gadget 1 selection doesn't work

Tags: battlefield-3

I have a huge problem with the key <kbd>3</kbd> which is default for the gadget 1 (rocket launcher, medpack and more). The problem is basically, that it doesn't matter what key I assign to that gadget 1 selection, it doesn't work. I even tried a mouse button and my joystick to make it work. I can't use this selection! I always have to use the mouse wheel to select my first gadget.

Does someone has an idea what I need to do?

[image]

Comment: can you provide screenshots?

Comment: @Foxtrot added screenshot to question

Comment: Thank you.  Are you positive you have ammo of that gadget?  (rocket ammo, etc)

Comment: absolutely. Played 144h and it never worked. Just had the time to try to fix it. If I switch 3 and 4, than 3 will work but select the gadget 2. Doesn't matter what key is bound to that gadget, it doesn't work...

Comment: Have you tried a different keyboard / input device driver ? Are you playing within a Virtural machine ?

Comment: I have a plain windows 7 installation and as I have tried 3 different input devices, I doubt that they should be the problem. I am currently installing it again... maybe it will solve the issue

Comment: @WarrenFaith Try to bind "Select Underslung Weapon" to the same key as "Select Gadget 1" and see if that helps.

Comment: Looks like it was the reason. Seriously not understandable why I need to have 2 keys for one action to make at least one work... @Krazer make this an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind "Select Underslung Weapon" to the same key as "Select Gadget 1" key.

It seems by default both "Select Gadget 1" and "Select Underslung Weapon" are the same key. I dunno why they did it this way... D:

Comment: I can confirm this worked (as of Jan 8, 2013)